# Spring boot micro service Deployment

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am new to Micro services architecture.. I want know if it is required to deploy all Spring boot micro services in the same local network ..? As Eureka Discovery service uses Private/Internal IP Address for Registration , i am unable to call a services from another service deployed in different local network...

Please let me know how micro services deployed across multiple Sub nets should communicate each other in this case

or is there a way to tell eureka to use only public IP Address..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help, but by default, your eureka client will try to connect to the default localhost:8761 where the eureka discovery server should exist.

In case you have a different location for your discovery-service you can use the following in the application.properties file in your client services.

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://{address}-{port}/eureka
```